# Mysql IN clause with something like not HAVING

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have been trying this from 1 week and I am not able to implement. I tried many ways, but not getting any solutions.
I will explain this below:

`options table:`

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
|   id    |    name   |    major   |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|    1    | option 1  |      1     |
|    2    | option 2  |      1     |
|    3    | option 3  |      1     |
|    4    | option 4  |      0     |
|    5    | option 5  |      0     |
|    6    | option 6  |      0     |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

`items table`

```
+---------+-----------+
|    id   |   name    |
+---------+-----------+
|    1    |  item 1   |
|    2    |  item 2   |
|    3    |  item 3   |
+---------+-----------+
```

`items_options`

```
+---------+-----------+
| item_id |option_id  |
+---------+-----------+
|    1    |    1      |
|    1    |    2      |
|    1    |    3      |
|    1    |    4      |
|    1    |    5      |
|    1    |    6      |
|    2    |    1      |
|    2    |    2      |
|    2    |    3      |
|    2    |    6      |
|    3    |    1      |
|    3    |    3      |
|    3    |    5      |
|    3    |    6      |
+---------+-----------+
```

So if I choose `items_options.option_id IN (1,3)` and `options.major = 1`,
I get:

```
+---------+----------+
| item_id |   name   |
+---------+----------+
|    1    |  item 1  |
|    2    |  item 2  |
|    3    |  item 3  |
+---------+----------+
```

But I should get the below:

```
+---------+----------+
| item_id |   name   |
+---------+----------+
|    3    |  item 3  |
+---------+----------+
```

I actually don't require the options which isn't major to be taken into account, But when I choose 1,3, I should get only the second result, if it has extra major options, then it should be not be in the list. Result should contain only the exact options, not more or less options.

MySQL Query which I tried:

```
SELECT items.id,items.name FROM items
INNER JOIN items_options ON items_options.option_id = items.id
INNER JOIN options ON options.id = items_options.option_id
WHERE items_options.option_id IN (1,3) AND options.major = 1
GROUP BY items.id
```

I do have only 3 major options, so I tried using the below too.
`HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT items_options.option_id) = 2` at the end

**EDIT 1:**

sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/280bf3/1

Comment: Can you setup a sqlfiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Sure, give me a minute

Comment: Added sqlfiddle, please check @JayBlanchard

Comment: How is `options.major` related to any of the other tables?

Comment: `options.major` is a status to show that major among other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the `count(distinct option_id)` when `option_id in (1,3)` to the count of `distinct option_id` overall, filtering by `major = 1`.

One way to do this is to use `COUNT` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT items.id, items.name
FROM items
  INNER JOIN items_options io ON io.item_id = items.id
  INNER JOIN options o ON io.option_id = o.id AND o.major = 1 
GROUP BY items.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT
             CASE WHEN io.option_id IN (1,3)
             THEN io.option_id
             END) = COUNT(DISTINCT io.option_id)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95a7f/9)

Comment: Not working, I tried `1,2,3`, I should get only item 2, but I get all 3 items.

Comment: Yes, I had tried this actually, the part which I am struck is, `1,2,3` should show only the `item 2`, but not `item 1` and `item 2`. where `item 1` has more `major` options, which should not be in the result

Comment: Hmmm, no its still showing both `item 1` and `item 2`. I don't even want to try with count. I can even try something like. `having 1,2 and not having 3` or `having 1,3 and not having 2` and so on.

Comment: @praveenkumar -- why should it not return item 1?  Item 1 has majors 1, 2 and 3 and no others.  Am I missing something?